# Using the rails notification plugin system_messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, notifications

I plan on using the [system_messages plugin](https://github.com/jstewart/system_messages#readme) for user notifications in my rails app. I have two questions:

1. The docs say: "You'll also want to create a CRUD interface to add SystemMessage records." What should this interface look like? Should the controller code be exactly the same as what scaffolding would provide you?
2. How would you customize content of notifications to include custom links and/or text?

Does anyone have any experience with this plugin??? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the system_messages plugin. I haven't used it in a long time (since 2008) and I'm sure that it will not work in Rails 3.

The CRUD interface can be exactly like what you get from scaffolding. It's really just an admin resource for add/deleting/updating objects like any other plain old resource.

To customize what's in the message with links or other content, you would just add it to the "message" field of the database.

Thanks for your interest in the plugin, and if you feel like making it Rails 3 compatible then pull requests are always welcome.